# How to get ldapsearch on Scientific Linux?

Tags: linux, redhat, ldap

How do I get the ldapsearch on Scientific Linux?

I am trying to find the ldapsearch client for Scientific Linux but cannot find how to install the client in order to do LDAP queries.

Comment: Since SL is based on RHEL wouldn't the install info for ldapsearch on RHEL work? http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapsearch  You may also look at OpenLDAP and see if that gets you the search tool you like.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use `yum whatprovides` to see what package provides a file. The following was run on SL6.x:

```
$ yum whatprovides */ldapsearch
...
openldap-clients-2.4.23-15.el6.x86_64 : LDAP client utilities
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/ldapsearch
```

Comment: Thank you!  `yum install openldap-clients -y` works.

Answer (score 16):

It's part of the openldap-clients package, so `yum install openldap-clients`.

The package contents are thus:

```
$ repoquery -lq openldap-clients
/usr/bin/ldapadd
/usr/bin/ldapcompare
/usr/bin/ldapdelete
/usr/bin/ldapexop
/usr/bin/ldapmodify
/usr/bin/ldapmodrdn
/usr/bin/ldappasswd
/usr/bin/ldapsearch
/usr/bin/ldapurl
/usr/bin/ldapwhoami
/usr/share/man/man1/ldapadd.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/ldapcompare.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/ldapdelete.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/ldapexop.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/ldapmodify.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/ldapmodrdn.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/ldappasswd.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/ldapsearch.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/ldapurl.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/ldapwhoami.1.gz
```